# Applying ifelse with a grouping variable

Tags: r, if-statement, group-by, tapply

I have data that contains an index and a season and would like to discretize this data. I created some fake data for demonstration:

```
data_frame <- data.frame(index=c(10,233.2,12,44,56,232,1.4,43,76,89,20.3,23), season=c('Fall','Winter','Fall','Summer','Winter','Spring','Spring','Summer','Winter','Spring','Summer','Fall'))
data_frame
   index season
1   10.0   Fall
2  233.2 Winter
3   12.0   Fall
4   44.0 Summer
5   56.0 Winter
6  232.0 Spring
7    1.4 Spring
8   43.0 Summer
9   76.0 Winter
10  89.0 Spring
11  20.3 Summer
12  23.0   Fall
```

Since in my original data, the distribution for each season is different, I would like to discretize the index grouping by the season variable. I am discretizing the data by assigning a 1 to anything above the 75th percentile for the group and 0 to anything below.

I would like the following output:

```
   index season  disc
1   10.0   Fall  0
2  233.2 Winter  1
3   12.0   Fall  0
4   44.0 Summer  1
5   56.0 Winter  0
6  232.0 Spring  1
7    1.4 Spring  0
8   43.0 Summer  0
9   76.0 Winter  0
10  89.0 Spring  0
11  20.3 Summer  0
12  23.0   Fall  1
```

I know how to find the result, but not in the format that I need. I am using the `tapply` function to discretize my variable:

```
tapply(data_frame$index, data_frame$season, function(x) ifelse(x>quantile(x,0.75),1,0))
$Fall
[1] 0 0 1

$Spring
[1] 1 0 0

$Summer
[1] 1 0 0

$Winter
[1] 1 0 0
```

How would I produce the output that I need?

Comment: `ave(data_frame$index, data_frame$season, FUN = function(x) ifelse(x>quantile(x,0.75),1,0))` ?

Comment: geez, I forgot about `ave`. Would you mind making this an answer?

Comment: Np, I sort of suspect that this question is a dupe, so I'll leave it as a comment. Anyone else can feel free to convert it to an answer if they want, though. I'd suggest taking up `dplyr` or `data.table` if you need to do group-by stuff often.

Comment: I'm actually using `data.table`. Does it have a better alternative to `ave`?

Comment: Oh, I meant `setDT(data_frame)[ , disc := +(x>quantile(x,0.75)), by=season]` Instead of a 0/1, you might also consider using R's `logical`/Boolean class for things like this.

Comment: I get the error `Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) :
  'x' must be atomic
`

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to test it. After replacing `x` with `index` it runs for me (on data.table 1.9.5): `setDT(data_frame)[ , disc := +(index>quantile(index,0.75)), by=season]`

Comment: @Frank, I have one more small question if possible. I actually have to apply this logic over a list of columns and not just one column. How would I do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87531/discussion-between-frank-and-michal).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame %>% group_by(season) %>%
               mutate(disc = +(percent_rank(index) > 0.75))

   index season disc
1   10.0   Fall    0
2  233.2 Winter    1
3   12.0   Fall    0
4   44.0 Summer    1
5   56.0 Winter    0
6  232.0 Spring    1
7    1.4 Spring    0
8   43.0 Summer    0
9   76.0 Winter    0
10  89.0 Spring    0
11  20.3 Summer    0
12  23.0   Fall    1
```

edit using `+` to convert the `TRUE` `FALSE` to numberic as per Frank

Comment: Integer is better than numeric for a binary var, eh? Fwiw, `+x` can be used  instead of `as.integer(x)` for a lower code golf score.

Comment: Same solution using the original function             data_frame %>% group_by(season) %>% mutate(disc = ifelse(index > quantile(index,0.75),1,0))

Comment: `+` is slightly pathological - great!